# how to get all posts on post.hbs page in ghost

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I want all posts on post.hbs but it's not displaying any post list, I want check title with my string and display particular post on post.hbs.

Below code is not working in post.hbs

```
{{#foreach posts}}
     <p>{{content}}</p>
{{/foreach}}`
```

Its not working on post.hbs page

Comment: what is post.hbs?
Is it just a file 

Have you tried to generate array and then print it like posts.content 
You can't get any content afaik in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Post.hbs is for displaying a specific post, so you are in {{post}} scope:

```
{{#post}}
{{/post}}
```

You can try something like this:

```
{{#get "posts" limit="all" as |allposts| }}
    {{#foreach allposts}}
       {{content}}
    {{/foreach}}
{{/get}}
```